# Magento(1.9) URL: Not able to remove store id from Magento url (.htaccess)

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, magento-1.9

I have gone through many tutorials, but I didn't get any relevant solution.
I am trying to remove store id `___store=` from Magento url, but it is not happening anyway. I have 5 stores in the backend and US store is the default one. Also each stores are restrict with geoIP.
My case is ->
1) I have already selected **Add Store Code to Urls** to **No** from Magento backend.
2) For eg: if I am looking for **Rahul Mishra Indelust** in google, and when I am clicking on result, the url redirects from

> `https://www.indelust.com/designer?d=332`

to

> `https://indelust.com/in/designer?___store=in_storeview&amp;d=332`

but it should redirect to

> `https://indelust.com/in/designer?d=332` (Remove `www` and
>   **`___store=in_storeview&amp;`**)

Please help me make this changes.

Below is my `.htaccess` file content.

```
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# CORS-enabled images (@crossorigin)
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Send CORS headers if browsers request them; enabled by default for images.
# developer.mozilla.org/en/CORS_Enabled_Image
# blog.chromium.org/2011/07/using-cross-domain-images-in-webgl-and.html
# hacks.mozilla.org/2011/11/using-cors-to-load-webgl-textures-from-cross-domain-images/
# wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Reviews/crossoriginAttribute
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # mod_headers, y u no match by Content-Type?!
    <FilesMatch "\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg|svgz|ico|webp)$">
      SetEnvIf Origin ":" IS_CORS
      Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" env=IS_CORS
    </FilesMatch>
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Webfont access
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Allow access from all domains for webfonts.
# Alternatively you could only whitelist your
# subdomains like "subdomain.example.com".
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2|font.css|css|js)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>



############################################
## uncomment these lines for CGI mode
## make sure to specify the correct cgi php binary file name
## it might be /cgi-bin/php-cgi

#    Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi
#    AddHandler php5-cgi .php

############################################
## GoDaddy specific options

#   Options -MultiViews

## you might also need to add this line to php.ini
##     cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
## if it still doesn't work, rename php.ini to php5.ini

############################################
## this line is specific for 1and1 hosting

#AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
#AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

############################################
## default index file

DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>

  ############################################
  ## adjust memory limit

  #    php_value memory_limit 64M
  php_value memory_limit 256M
  php_value max_execution_time 18000

  ############################################
  ## disable magic quotes for php request vars

  php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

  ############################################
  ## disable automatic session start
  ## before autoload was initialized

  php_flag session.auto_start off

  ############################################
  ## enable resulting html compression

  php_flag zlib.output_compression on

  ###########################################
  # disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

  php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off

  ###########################################
  # turn off compatibility with PHP4 when dealing with objects

  php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
  ###########################################
  # disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

  SecFilterEngine Off
  SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

  ############################################
  ## enable apache served files compression
  ## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

  # Insert filter on all content
  ###SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
  # Insert filter on selected content types only
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript

  # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

  # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

  # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

  # Don't compress images
  SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

  # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
  Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

  ############################################
  ## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

  SSLOptions StdEnvVars

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  ############################################
  ## enable rewrites

  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine on

  ############################################
  ## you can put here your magento root folder
  ## path relative to web root

  #RewriteBase /magento/

  ############################################
  ## uncomment next line to enable light API calls processing

  #    RewriteRule ^api/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]

  ############################################
  ## rewrite API2 calls to api.php (by now it is REST only)

  RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]
  ############################################
  ## redirect to ssl

 # RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
 # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^indelust\.com$ [NC]
 # RewriteRule ^ https://www.indelust.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

 # RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on 
 # RewriteRule ^catalogsearch http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
  ############################################
  ## workaround for HTTP authorization
  ## in CGI environment

  RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

  ############################################
  ## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
  RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

  ############################################
  ## redirect for mobile user agents

  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
  #RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
  #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]

  ############################################
  ## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

  ############################################
  ## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

  ############################################
  ## rewrite everything else to index.php

  RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>


############################################
## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

AddDefaultCharset Off
#AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On

  ############################################
  ## Add default Expires header
  ## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"

  ExpiresByType image/* "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType text/* "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>

############################################
## By default allow all access

Order allow,deny
Allow from all

###########################################
## Deny access to release notes to prevent disclosure of the installed Magento version

<Files RELEASE_NOTES.txt>
  order allow,deny
  deny from all
</Files>

############################################
## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

#FileETag none
FileETag -INode
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your .htaccess file
2. Look for "RewriteEngine on"
3. Paste these two lines below it:
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^indelust.com$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://indelust.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: Hi @Ashwin, I tried to make the above changes, but it is not redirecting the website based on ip address.

Comment: Oh, it'd be great if you could paste the .htaccess code so that I can see what you're actually doing.

Comment: Hi @Ashwin, I have added .htaccess file content in my question.

Comment: Hi @VaibhavDass, I hadn't checked the links you'd mentioned earlier. Just did and what I found was there is no actual redirection on the URL itself. However, while inspecting your site I found that it's quite probably an SEO on-page problem. Looks like you've an SEO plugin installed in the backend. Can you tell me which one?

Comment: Hi @Ashwin, how do I find SEO plugin, because as per my knowledge, we have not installed any SEO plugin in the backend.

Comment: you can also check this thread, this is also related with same thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31933651/is-there-any-way-to-replace-amp-with-in-magento-url

Comment: Go to System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Disable Modules Output. You should find a list of modules installed in your Magento installation. Try and locate a name which contains SEO or anything to do with "search."